# Is there a way to see the coded value domain list of possible values from arcmap 9.3.1?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-9.3, domains

Is there a way to see the possible values of a specific  coded value domain in arcmap 9.3.1 (I have no access to the SDE which holds all the data in arcCatalog)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you asking about outside of an edit session?
If you have access to the data in arcmap you have access to the data in arccatalog.
In arcmap there is a small button at the top with a "yellow file cabinet" catalog.
If you access the data in arcmap, ArcCatalog is how that connection is created.
Does IT have that locked down?
 a. If you have the data in arcmap and you go to the layer properties> symbology dialog.
Select the domain field on categories, and add all values.
[image: coded value]

b. If you can edit when you are in an edit session and select the field (in the attribute table) it should be a pulldown with all the possible values.

Hope I'm not stepping on any IT toes here, but...
NOT
when you open arcmap if you don't have to type a password then you have a connection to sde with the password in it.
They may have it hidden in a secured location but the normal place for those  *.sde files is in the... 
 C:\Documents and Settings\myusername\Application Data\ESRI\Desktop10.0\ArcCatalog\Connection to mysde.sde.
If you open arccatalog and go to the sde connection and right click> select properties "not connection properties"
[image: connection]
That dialog has two valuable pieces of information.
one the location of the sde (connection) file.
two the name and values of the domains. Note the domains tab (v10 may not be true for 9.3.1)
[image: connection]

Once you have acces to that connection you could do the following.
OR request your admin do it for you.
Just create a one time table for you to use as reference. 
go to arctoolbox...
[image: arctoolbox]
use the domain to table tool to create a txt, dbf, gdb table, or info file (gdb table shown)you can use in arcmap, or excel.
[image: domain2table]

Comment: I can enter ArcCatalog but to access the SDE database I needa password which I'm refused to get. A. in the layer properties I cannot see the values B. in the edit I can see all values in the pulldown (thanks!) but I can only see the aliases, not the codes which is the more essential thing.

Comment: if none of this works your admin has created an application to push a password into the connection when you start arcmap. in which case you are probably out of luck (except the choice in b.). You should request an excel file from the domain to table tool.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried running the [Domain to Table](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000022000000) tool?  This will give you a listing of all domains and associated code values.  And it is available at all license levels.

Answer (score 0):

Export the feature class to a shapefile. Instead of aliases you should have the actual value.

Or you could do a summarize for the domain field. the result will give you the values, if i'm not mistaken.

Comment: it's possible (theoretically) - but it's loads of work, as I'd have to record the actual values and then go back to the original to record the aliases which match.